# Can't use the Number() function in my express.js server - RangeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I Have the following HTML Form:

```
<form class="" action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="First Number">
      <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Second Number">
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button>
    </form>
```

What I want to do is to get the two entered numbers and post their sum.
In my express.js server, I included the body-parser package and when I write the following route:

```
  app.post("/", function(req,res) {

  var num1 = Number(req.body.num1);
  var num2 = Number(req.body.num2);

  res.send(num1+num2);

})
```

After pressing the submit button, I get the following error showing:

RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 5

I also tried using the parseInt() function but it displayed the same error.

What does this error mean? And how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you receive for `req.body.num1` and `req.body.num2`?

Comment: its gives me the two inputs the user entered. The problem is that those values are strings, so I cant sum their app. Therefor, I needed to parse them to Integers.

Comment: Also, your error doesn't seem at all connected to the use of `Number` - it claims that the *status code* is incorrect and it's `5`. This isn't a valid status code which is what the error you get is saying. Somewhere you're changing the status code of the response.

Comment: Are you sure you're not doing `res.status(num1+num2)`? That would make more sense considering the error message.

Comment: when I remove the Number() and run the program, it gives me the incorrect answer. For example, if the two numbers the user entered are 3 and 5, it sends 35. This error only occurs when I include the Number() function.

Comment: `res.send([body])` can't receive a Number as parameter: [see doc](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.send)

Comment: express 4.x treats `res.send(<number>)` as `res.send(status, body)` ([source](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/dc538f6e810bd462c98ee7e6aae24c64d4b1da93/lib/response.js#L123)). This behavior got changed with 5.x ([Source](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/f4120a645301366891775d1f03925449239a2cb7/lib/response.js#L123))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting the return value to String.

```
res.send(String(num1 + num2));
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the doc
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send
`res.send` expects Buffer object, a String, an object, Boolean, or an Array

Assuming you have `body-parser` configured you can use

`res.send([num1 + num2])` to get the result